# Reference Error From Windows Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-4

I am facing one issue when referencing on namespace.

I have create two Different Project in one solution

1. Class Library Project.
2. Windows Service Project

Class Library Project namespace is **PRC.B2B.Common** and
Windows Service Project namespace is **PRC.B2B.SchedulerService**

I am facing one issue about referencing class library project in Windows Service Project.

I want to refer **PRC.B2B.Common** in **PRC.B2B.SchedulerService**
but after adding reference and trying to access the namespace there is no error but when i try to build the project i am getting below error :-

Issue Says

The type or namespace name 'Common' does not exist in the namespace **PRC.B2B.Common** (are you missing an assembly reference?

I am not certain with windows application, what could be the issue ?

Comment: Can you post the line that the error occurs at? Chances are that there is one "Common" too much (maybe you referenced the type including the Namespace before adding the Import).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the properties of your windows service project and change the target framework to something other than client profile.

Answer (score 0):

Check Traget Framework and PlatformTarget in Project Properties/Build was same.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for quick reference it was only the issue of framework difference.

1)**PRC.B2B.SchedulerService** was working on the .net framework 4 client profile.
2)**PRC.B2B.Common** was working with .net framework 4.

So changed the framework of Windows Service by selecting the project and going to properties..